# Javascript - Decimais e Zeros à esquerda

Tags: javascript

poderiam, me ajudar com a seguinte situação:

Possuo um campo Numérico (21,2) e preciso formatá-lo para um layout específico, conforme abaixo.

Exemplo de Input's:

VALOR1:  3500.31    -> Após Formatação: +00000000000003500.31

VALOR2: -3000       -> Após Formatação: -00000000000003000.00

VALOR3:  2000.00    -> Após Formatação: +00000000000002000.00

Estou utilizando a função abaixo para preenchimento dos 0 à esquerda e validação do sinal, porém estou com um problema, para os casos onde o input é um inteiro, desta forma o campo na fica no formato #.00 :

Saída: +00000000000000003000

Função:

```
function leadingZero(value, totalWidth, paddingChar) {

     var length = totalWidth - value.toString().length + 1;
     return Array(length).join(paddingChar || '0') + value;
   };


    if (total_amount >=0){

       var total_amount = '+' + leadingZero(total_amount,20);

    } else {

       var total_amount = '-' + leadingZero(replace(total_amount,'-',''),20);

    }
```

Obrigado!

Comment: De novo? Qual a diferença para sua outra pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257573/5878

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Função Javascript para formatação de campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257573/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-javascript-para-formata%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-campo)

Comment: Apesar de já ter uma resposta, sua pergunta está meio confusa: de onde vem o parâmetro `paddingChar`? Você está tentado inserir novo valor no campo? Isso é PHP?

Comment: @ÐvÐ o paddingChar esta por default 0, porem ele é o valor ao qual eu vou adicionar a string.

Comment: A resposta do Sergio não resolveu o problema?

Comment: @ÐvÐ resolveu sim..

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro separar em 3 passos:

- garantir que o numero tem 2 casas decimais
- ter uma string de zeros com o comprimento máximo possível para juntar ao valor absoluto em questão
- juntar o sinal `+`/`-`

e isso poderia ser feito assim:

```js
function leadingZeros(nr) {
  const zeros = '0000000000000000';
  const sign = nr >= 0 ? '+' : '-';
  const numberString = zeros + Math.abs(nr).toFixed(2);
  return sign + numberString.slice(-20);
}

console.log(leadingZeros(3500.31));
console.log(leadingZeros(-3000));
console.log(leadingZeros(3000));
console.log(leadingZeros(2000.00));
```

Comment: O mal de usar `const`é que não funciona no IE 10 pra baixo. Mas...

Comment: @ÐvÐ exato. Mudando para `var` onde está `const` já fica compatível com browsers descontinuados.

Comment: A resposta é ótima, só há um probleminha: pelo que entendi, a saída deve ter 21 caracteres. As suas só possuem 18. Acho que dá pra arrumar fácil.

Comment: @ÐvÐ obrigado, ajustei.

Comment: Sergio.. muito obrigado! com certeza uma ótima solução.